# Price mark is showing up twice

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

On virtuemart (Joomla) i am noticing that on each of the items the price is showing up twice. Once in English and once in French. I believe it has something to do with the language extension, anyone know how i can fix this?

I am using the latest versions of joomla and virtuemart.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Joomla cms 2.0.18a ?? Get the site to Joomla 2.5.11 which is the latest version of the 2.5 series first

Comment: I cant do that. i am using the latest virtuemart though.

Comment: 2.0.18a isn't even a version of Joomla, it's a number of the alpha version of VirtueMart but you said you were using 2.0 VirtueMart. So which is it? If you're using an older version of VirtueMart, then upgrade to the latest version as the older one might have bugs. There is no reason to be using older versions

Comment: maybe also provide a link to the site

Comment: Lets just say i am using the latest version of everything... do you know what and where is causing the price to show twice? I cant provide the link to the website.

Comment: found this: http://www.joomlahackers.net/virtuemart-tutorials/virtuemart-duplicate-orders.html

Comment: and did the solution on this page work?

Comment: i am trying to find the code he posted, no luck so far... but it kind of gives me an idea of what the problem maybe... what do you think?

Comment: I'm not too sure if it will fix it as I never use VirtueMart. Go to `administrator/components/com_virtuemart/html/order.order_list.php`, press `CTRL + F` and type in `$list  = "SELECT` to find it quickly

Comment: yes i saw that and i am quite familiar with computers.. but that file doesnt exists on mine :)

Comment: can anyone who is familiar to virtuemart please help? thanks!